# wierd MySql join behavior

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, query-optimization

I have a MySql database with 4 tables (a lot more than that, actually, but only these 4 are relevant to the question), lets call them A, B, C, and D. Here's the Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  pKey INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name NVARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY(pKey),
  UNIQUE INDEX(name)
);

CREATE TABLE C
(
  pKey INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(pKey)
);

CREATE TABLE B
(
  pKey INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  aKey INT NOT NULL,
  cKey INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(pKey),
  UNIQUE INDEX UniqueKey (aKey, cKey),
  FOREIGN KEY(aKey) REFERENCES A(pKey),
  FOREIGN KEY(cKey) REFERENCES C(pKey)
);

CREATE TABLE D
(
  pKey INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cKey INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(pKey),
  INDEX(cKey),
  FOREIGN KEY(cKey) REFERENCES C(pKey)
);
```

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT 
    --stuff...
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B
    ON A.pKey=B.aKey
INNER JOIN C
    ON B.cKey=C.pKey
INNER JOIN D
    ON D.cKey=C.pKey
WHERE
    A.name=parameter_1;
```

The trouble is, this is a large database running on a single server, and most tables have 100K+ records, and its not uncommon for a table to break 10 million records. One table has more than 200 million records.

Leaving aside any problems with MySql and the architecture (I'm stuck with both), I'm getting some odd behavior with the above query when I use explain on this query. Because of this behavior I have several questions. I'll show the odd behavior first.

If I just EXPLAIN the above query in MySql, then I get the references I would expect in the *ref* column of the EXPLAIN output. However, I need to run this query as a sub-query of a larger query. EXPLAINning the larger query gives me something like this for the above query (this is JUST the rows of the larger query that correspond to the tables in this query):

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys       | key     | key_len | ref             | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | A     | const | PRIMARY,key1,key2   | key1    | 38      |                 |     1 |                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | D     | index | key3                | key3    | 12      | NULL            | 73868 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | C     | index | PRIMARY,key3        | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL            |     1 |                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | B     | ref   | key4,UniqueKey,key6 | key4    | 12      | const,DB.D.key3 |     1 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------+---------+-----------------+-------+--------------------------+
```

MySql is doing two index scans, and one ref type join. I can improve this slightly if I use index hints, but only slightly. I said earlier that this query is run as a sub-query. Here's the format of that other query:

```
SELECT
  --stuff
FROM
(
  --sub-query1
) a
INNER JOIN
(
  --the query I have a question about
) b
ON a.c1=b.c2
```

The optimizer is totally ignoring table C in favor of doing join on the two foreign key columns, B.cKey=D.cKey. **So here's question 1) Why is the optimizer ignoring table C like this?**

Next, even if I do use index hints, and it ignores table C, it still does an index scan to join B and D despite appropriate indexes. **Why?**

In the above explain, it shows that there are 73,868 rows in table D. There are actually 73,568 rows at the time of this question. One of the other tables being queried (not shown in this question) has about 100 million rows, so optimizing this is rather important. For the full query, the product of rows column is about 2.37E42. And yes, I have already considered ways to reduce the number of tables in the query; the information I need to get requires every table I'm accessing and I can't change the architecture of the database.

Finally, the only things that I can change here are the query and indexes/constraints. I'm stuck with everything else since this is a preexisting system. **Are there any other ways that I can optimize this operation more?**

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I fixed the formatting for the super query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add an index to this schema?

If so, I suggest you add the compound index `(name, pKey)` to your table `A`. Don't bother to put a unique constraint on it; you've already handled that with your other indexes. That compound will allow your selection criterion `A.name=parameter_1` and your join to be satisfied with one index scan.

Your use of the single-column table C is simply to eliminate resultset rows that aren't in that table. I wouldn't worry about it being missing from `EXPLAIN` unless you have horrible performance problems with your query.

In general, when handling these multiway join operations, you should try to use compound covering indexes to help your performance. You can read about that kind of index.

Comment: I added the index you suggested, and there was no difference. Table C actually has more columns that the one primary key, and I am selecting values from some of those columns. Since I didn't think those additional columns were relevant to the JOIN operation, I didn't include them.